# Embedded PDF in PowerPoint opening on second screen

Tags: pdf, powerpoint

I have a PDF embedded in a PowerPoint, set up to open when I click on its icon. When I do, nothing appears to happen unless I'm using two screens where I see the PDF open on the second screen.

When I have one screen, I know the PDF is opening because when I end the slideshow, I briefly see the PDF reader software closing down.

Does anyone know how to fix this, so that the PDF opens on the same screen as the slideshow?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: For non-programming questions, SuperUser (also part of StackExchange) is the better choice